# how to use a section in multiple pages without creating duplicates of it[Shopify]?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

**Problem**

So i am making a designer's page in which there are different pages for a designer. I want each page to be fully customize able from the admin panel. So, I am making use of the sections. So what I did is, I copied the the section code into a custom page template. Then I made a page from admin panel and assigned that(custom page template) to that page. Then I did the same for another page and assigned the same custom template to the other page.

But the problem is that If I change something from one page(admin panel), it's changing the other page too.

**My Solution**

I solved the problem by making a separate template + section for every page. But, I feel like this is not the best solution and surely not scale able.

**Question**

What is the best solution to tackle this problem without making separate sections or templates for every other page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible for the moment.

However, Shopify has announced recently that this possibility is coming soon (already available via dev preview):
https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/shopify-unite-announcements-2019#onlinestore1

Comment: Thanks! for your help.